# Android - do Bitmaps automatically get recycled when an activity finish()?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-memory

Do Bitmaps automatically get recycled when an activity `finish()`?

Or do we have to call `recycle()` the bitmaps in `onDestroy()`?

Comment: Short answer: If you don't have another thread referencing it, it will be GC'ed after the UI thread gets shut down.

Comment: @Edison by 'referencing it' you mean referencing the bitmap?

Comment: Yes, holding the object to another variable. Actually Per @blackbelt's comment, you should recycle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Pre Android 3.0 you need to `recycle` it, because the bitmap is stored in the `native heap`.

Answer (score 2):

as long as you're not referencing them by any still alive object: they get garbage collected by the GC without any need to further interaction.

Comment: so I don't need to call recycle()? How about pre-android 3.0 as mentioned by 'blackbelt' in the other answer?

Answer (score 0):

On Pre-honeycomb device

- Bitmap Object reference allocated on Dalvik Heap
- Pixel information stored on Native layer
- `recycle()` or `finalizer()` needed to restore memory

On Post honeycomb its standard like any java object